# Bad access on NULL termination of the string

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

```
-(void)myStartMethod{
    NSString *str = @"testing";
    char *charStr = [str UTF8String];
    charStr[4] = '\0'; // bad access on this line.
    NSLog(@"%s",charStr);
}
```

I am trying to terminate the string on fourth char and print the output as "test".
What am I missed?

Since `C` programing can be as it is used with `Objective-c(foundation framework)`, then why it is throwing bad access. This type of char array modification is totally valid in `C (GCC)`.

How can i avoid it and reason behind it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably mean “null-termination”. NULL is the name of a null pointer. “null-terminated” refers to the null character.

Comment: `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const char *'` - would seem a pretty solid hint what you're trying to do isn't allowed, and in-fact will fail to even compile if you turn up your warnings loud enough.

Comment: What you are missing is the line in the NSString documentation that says you are allowed to modify the C string returned by the UTF8String method. The reason why you are missing that line is because it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) states provides a pretty good hint:

> **UTF8String**
>
> Returns a null-terminated UTF8 representation of the receiver.
>
> `- (const char *)UTF8String`

So, clearly you're in error for modifying this. In fact, you should have gotten a warning for converting `const char *` to plain `char *`.

Also, the name of the `'\0'` character is not `NULL`, that's used for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

As apple headers `[str UTF8String]` returns a `const char*` which can't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have mentioned, you cannot modify the UTF-8 string returned from an `NSString` instance.

Instead use this code:

```
-(void)myStartMethod{
    NSString *str = @"testing";
    NSString *part = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
    char *charStr = [part UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"%s",charStr);
}
```

or:

```
-(void)myStartMethod{
    NSString *str = @"testing";
    NSString *part = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
    NSLog(@"%@", part);
}
```